# How to read (out of memory) a large matrix with an arrow package R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

imagine that I have a huge matrix (small example)

```
dat <- matrix(1:100,ncol = 10) 
colnames(dat) <- paste0("X",1:ncol(dat))
dat
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
 [1,]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
 [2,]  2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
 [3,]  3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
 [4,]  4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
 [5,]  5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
 [6,]  6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86  96
 [7,]  7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87  97
```

this matrix is divided into `columns` and written in several files

```
path <- paste0(getwd(),"/example/")
dir.create(path = path)
colum_id <- matrix(1:10,ncol = 2,byrow = T)
for(i in 1:nrow(colum_id)) write.csv(dat[,colum_id[i,]], file = paste0(path,i,".csv"), row.names = F)
```

files in a folder

```
 dir(path)
[1] "1.csv" "2.csv" "3.csv" "4.csv" "5.csv"
```

...

```
paths <- paste0(path,dir(path))
lapply(paths , \(Path) head(read.csv(Path),2) )

[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1 11
2  2 12

[[2]]
  X3 X4
1 21 31
2 22 32

[[3]]
  X5 X6
1 41 51
2 42 52

[[4]]
  X7 X8
1 61 71
2 62 72

[[5]]
  X9 X10
1 81  91
2 82  92
```

The question is how can I read this matrix (out of memory) in the `arrow` so that I can access to any element of the full matrix.

All the examples that I saw with the use of the `arrow` were with reading files separated by lines but not by columns.

I would also like to hear other packages that can do such things(out of memory).

Comment: While `arrow` supports reading multiple parquet files and internally concatenating them row-wise, I don't know of a way for it to happen column-wise (still OOM). You can read them in to individual connections via `arrow::open_csv_dataset`, and then individually filter them. My guess, however, is that you're going to want to do multi-column filtering before collection, is that right? Is there a reason you cannot column-wide concatenate them on the filesystem before using a single call to `open_csv_dataset`?

Comment: `concatenate them on the filesystem before using a single call ` - 
each individual file is quite large for my memory, in order for me to combine them, I first need to load all the files into memory, right? Or is there a way to do it out of memory?

Comment: I'm suggesting not in R, and there are likely ways you can achieve this with shell scripting (tends to be much more memory-efficient) and effected in batched. Does this mean you're amenable to a not-R workaround to column-wise concatenate the files for easier access? (This has a lot more benefit if you intend to filter concurrently on fields from different files.)

Comment: thanks i will keep this method in mind